# How to optimize the code any further?

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist, hashset

A very good day to all of you.

I have code which does exactly what a Excel Pivot does in the matter of few seconds. Whereas, my code does the same thing in not less than 30 minutes. I am awestruck with the difference! I am pretty sure I can optimize my code to make much faster than currently. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Please have a quick look at the code. If necessary I will explain in detail what exactly it does. Thank you!

```
public void countImages(ArrayList<String> all) throws IOException {
        HashSet<String> uStrings = new HashSet<>();
        int Counter = 0;
        int C500x500 = 0;
        int C800x800 = 0;
        int C1000x1000 = 0;
        int G1000x1000 = 0;
        write("Vendor ID, Count of Images, Less than 500 x 500, Less than 800 x 800, Less than 1000 x 1000, Greater than 1000 x 1000", "ImageCount_Data");
        for (String single : all) {
            String[] linearray = single.split(",");
            uStrings.add(linearray[0]);
        }
        totallines = uStrings.size();
        completedlines = 0;
        percentage = 0;
        setPercent(0);
        for (String uString : uStrings) {
            Counter = 0;
            C500x500 = 0;
            C800x800 = 0;
            C1000x1000 = 0;
            G1000x1000 = 0;
            for (String single : all) {
                String[] linearray = single.split(",");
                if (linearray[0].equals(uString)) Counter++;
                if ((linearray[1].equals("Less than 500 x 500")) && linearray[0].equals(uString)) C500x500++;
                if ((linearray[1].equals("Less than 800 x 800")) && linearray[0].equals(uString)) C800x800++;
                if ((linearray[1].equals("Less than 1000 x 1000")) && linearray[0].equals(uString)) C1000x1000++;
                if ((linearray[1].equals("Greater than 1000 x 1000")) && linearray[0].equals(uString)) G1000x1000++;
            } //END OF 2ND FOR LOOP
            write(uString + "," + Counter + "," + C500x500 + "," + C800x800 + "," + C1000x1000 + "," + G1000x1000, "ImageCount_Data");
            completedlines++;
            percentage = (completedlines / totallines) * 100;
            setPercent(Math.round(percentage));
            Icwindow.frame.setTitle("Writing Image Count Data: " + getPercent() + "%");
        } //END OF 1ST FOR LOOP
        Icwindow.frame.setTitle("Process Cloudinary ImageCount Data");
    }
```

Comment: You have three loops, i believe you can do it with just one.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over all possible strings in column zero, then iterate over all strings again within that loop. Thus your algorithm is O(n²), where Excel gets away with a faster (likely O(n) amortized) algorithm.

You could use a `HashMap<String, Counts>` to keep track of counts with only one for loop instead of two nested loops.

The `Counts` object would then contain the counts for your classes, as in:

```
class Counts {
    int c500;
    int c800;
    int c1000;
    int cOther;

    void count(String s) {
        switch(s) {
        case "Less than 500 x 500": c500++; break;
        case "Less than 500 x 500": c800++; break;
        case "Less than 500 x 500": c1000++; break;
        case "Greater than 1000 x 1000": cOther++; break;
        default: throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
}
```

Another hint: You can get the global counter by adding `c500 + c800 + c1000 + cOther`.

Comment: Thank you llogiq! Someone did tell me that the last time I was doing a similar program but, I didn't really get it, how I do it. Can you please help me with a short example code?

Comment: I think, I'm getting it. So that will solve my count problem once. However, I am counting repetitions for 3 different strings. How do I achieve that in one single loop?

Comment: I added an example snippet to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!

Below is my new code which uses Hash Map and it is indeed much much faster than my previous code. However, there appears to be something incorrect in the code cause the count is correct only for the first Hash Map and rest 4 Has Maps have incorrect count. May I request you take a look and tell me if you notice anything odd in the new code?

EDIT - I missed adding breaks in switch case statements! This works perfectly & fast! :D

```
public void countImages(ArrayList<String> all) throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> c500 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> c800 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> c1000 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> g1000 = new HashMap<>();

        write("Vendor ID, Count of Images, Less than 500 x 500, Less than 800 x 800, Less than 1000 x 1000, Greater than 1000 x 1000", "ImageCount_Data");

        for (String single : all) {
            String[] linearray = single.split(",");
            if (!counter.containsKey(linearray[0])) {
                counter.put(linearray[0], 1);
            } else {
                counter.put(linearray[0], counter.get(linearray[0]) + 1);
            }

            switch (linearray[1]) {

            case "Less than 500 x 500" :
                if (!c500.containsKey(linearray[0])) {
                    c500.put(linearray[0], 1);
                } else {
                    c500.put(linearray[0], c500.get(linearray[0]) + 1);
                }
            case "Less than 800 x 800" :
                if (!c800.containsKey(linearray[0])) {
                    c800.put(linearray[0], 1);
                } else {
                    c800.put(linearray[0], c800.get(linearray[0]) + 1);
                }
            case "Less than 1000 x 1000":
                if (!c1000.containsKey(linearray[0])) {
                    c1000.put(linearray[0], 1);
                } else {
                    c1000.put(linearray[0], c1000.get(linearray[0]) + 1);
                }
            case "Greater than 1000 x 1000" :
                if (!g1000.containsKey(linearray[0])) {
                    g1000.put(linearray[0], 1);
                } else {
                    g1000.put(linearray[0], g1000.get(linearray[0]) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (String key : counter.keySet()) {
            write(key + "," + counter.get(key) + "," + c500.get(key) + "," + c800.get(key) + "," + c1000.get(key) + "," + g1000.get(key), "ImageCount_Data");
        }

    }
```